Comedy skit parodying the "Daylight Robbery" VHS piracy warning
Some time in the late 1990s or early 2000s, I saw a comedy sketch parodying the "Daylight Robbery" VHS piracy warning wherein a hapless punter remonstrates with a video pirate on his market stall and attempts to gain a refund.
The parody had an actor (possibly even the same actor as the original?) complaining that his pirated video was not working because it was a 'block of cheese' (in the shape of a VHS tape). He is told by the market trader "That'll be your tracking". He exclaims "But it's cheese!" and is told that "it's touchy, is tracking".

Per Reddit "*,There was also a "Daylight Robbery" parody series of skits in I think The Fast Show. Each variation had even worse consequences for buying pirate videos.
One was "I bought this video off you last week and it turned out to be a block of cheese." and another was "I bought this video off you last week, and now my Mum won't stop getting off with my friends. So don't buy pirate videos or your Mum might turn into the town bike."* - https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/8m9o46/comment/dzn0j5m/

I don't remember there being any others in the same show, so I've posted this as a comment
